# H10 error deploying react native project to Heroku using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, heroku, frontend

I have problems deploying my simple frontend project to heroku (I deploy my backend with java spring in another app with not problems). I tried to get help from the heroku-support, but they could not find the problem. Im using react native for the project. Ive read alot of threads and tried many hours before posting this.

**in my package.json file I have:**

```
{
"name": "AwesomeProject2",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"main": "index.js",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
"android": "react-native run-android",
"ios": "react-native run-ios",
"lint": "eslint .",
"start": "node index.js",
"test": "jest"
},
```

etc

**in my Procfile I have:**
web: node ./index.js

**The error I get is:**

```
2023-05-23T15:32:00.000000+00:00 app\[api\]: Build succeeded  
2023-05-23T15:32:03.085414+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: Starting process with command `node ./index.js`  
2023-05-23T15:32:04.338023+00:00 app\[web.1\]: node:internal/errors:490  
2023-05-23T15:32:04.338070+00:00 app\[web.1\]: ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);  
2023-05-23T15:32:10.297744+00:00 app\[web.1\]: at ModuleWrap.\<anonymous\>       (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)  
2023-05-23T15:32:10.297745+00:00 app\[web.1\]: at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {  
2023-05-23T15:32:10.297745+00:00 app\[web.1\]: code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'  
2023-05-23T15:32:10.297746+00:00 app\[web.1\]: }  
2023-05-23T15:32:10.297746+00:00 app\[web.1\]:  
2023-05-23T15:32:10.297746+00:00 app\[web.1\]: Node.js v18.16.0  
2023-05-23T15:32:10.422614+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: Process exited with status 1  
2023-05-23T15:32:10.454163+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed  
2023-05-23T15:32:12.908871+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET     path="/" host=pleasework123-frontend.herokuapp.com request_id=811ba6a8-e29b-4971-b774-d150dc2a4273 fw
```

Ive tried changing Procfile and package.json settings. Ive tried using react vite. Ive tried reinstallning node.